# Rails - Escaping JavaScript in error proc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a custom error proc that gets initialised in **application.rb**:

```
config.action_view.field_error_proc = Proc.new do |html_tag, object|
  error_msg = object.error_message.join(", ")
  "<span class='field_with_errors' data-error='#{error_msg}'>#{html_tag}</span>".html_safe
end
```

I would like to escape javascript, so I modify it:

```
config.action_view.field_error_proc = Proc.new do |html_tag, object|
  error_msg = object.error_message.join(", ")
  "<span class='field_with_errors' data-error='#{escape_javascript(error_msg)}'>#{html_tag}</span>".html_safe
end
```

However I get the following error:

```
undefined method `escape_javascript' for #<MyApp::Application:0x00000006edd2e8>
```

I'm using **rails 3.0**

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to include the helper in order for it to be available. This should work:

```
include ActionView::Helpers::JavaScriptHelper

config.action_view.field_error_proc = Proc.new do |html_tag, object|
  error_msg = object.error_message.join(", ")
  "<span class='field_with_errors' data-error='#{escape_javascript(error_msg)}'>#{html_tag}</span>".html_safe
end
```